# What is the default mode in GoColly, sync or async?

Tags: go, asynchronous, go-colly

What is the default mode in which network requests are executed in GoColly? Since we have the `Async` method in the collector I would assume that the default mode is synchronous.
However, I see no particular difference when I execute these 8 requests in the program other than I need to use `Wait` for async mode. It seems as if the method only controls how the program is executed (the other code) and the requests are always asynchronous.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gocolly/colly/v2"
)

func main() {

    urls := []string{
        "http://webcode.me",
        "https://example.com",
        "http://httpbin.org",
        "https://www.perl.org",
        "https://www.php.net",
        "https://www.python.org",
        "https://code.visualstudio.com",
        "https://clojure.org",
    }

    c := colly.NewCollector(
        colly.Async(true),
    )

    c.OnHTML("title", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        fmt.Println(e.Text)
    })

    for _, url := range urls {

        c.Visit(url)
    }

    c.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default collection **is** synchronous.

The confusing bit is probably the collector option [`colly.Async()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gocolly/colly#Async) which ignores the actual param. In fact the implementation at the time of writing is:

```
func Async(a ...bool) CollectorOption {
    return func(c *Collector) {
        c.Async = true // uh-oh...!
    }
}
```

Based on [this issue](https://github.com/gocolly/colly/issues/530), it was done this way for backwards compatibility, so that (I believe) you can pass an option with no param at it'll still work, e.g.:

```
colly.NewCollector(colly.Async()) // no param, async collection
```

If you remove the async option altogether and instantiate with just `colly.NewCollector()`, the network requests will be clearly sequential — i.e. you can also remove `c.Wait()` and the program won't exit right away.